# Approval dates for drugs from FDA?

Tags: openfda

OpenFDA is awesome! I wish we had anything similar here in the UK.

Is there a way to get drug approval dates via the API? I'm interested in knowing what date a drug was approved by the FDA.

I think this exists in the API for devices, but I can't see the information [in queries for drugs](https://api.fda.gov/drug/label.json?search=generic_name:atorvastatin).

The data [exists on the FDA website](http://www.accessdata.fda.gov/scripts/cder/drugsatfda/index.cfm?fuseaction=Reports.ReportsMenu), but it would be awesome if these could be retrieved through the API too.

Comment: It does not seem to be available but you can scrape it.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like that information is available. Might want to file a feature request on GitHub.